# XML Parsing of Multiline tags

Tags: iphone, url, query-string

I am using XML Parsing in one of my apps. I have not done this before but I observed something weird (or may be now) today. I am trying to locate a business on in my app and their googlemaps link is obviously big

`http://maps.google.com/maps?f=q&source=s_q&hl=en&geocode=&q=1001+Fannin+Street,+Houston,+TX&aq=0&sll=37.0625,-95.677068&sspn=36.999937,73.476563&ie=UTF8&hq=&hnear=1001+Fannin+St,+Houston,+Harris,+Texas+77002&z=16`.

Every time I load using this link the app crashes. However if I change the link to something like :

`http://maps.google.com/?saddr=0000+FM+0000+RD+Houston+TX+77000`

the app loads perfectly and works perfect.

I know this is not a problem in my app as I am using this just for reference to something else and not loading the addr in google maps app (as this works with the big link). So I am concluding that there is something wrong in the way I am writing it in my XML.

Please do not direct me to any tools and stuff that shorten the link etc. as I dont want to get in to that. I am sure that I am messing up somewhere in my basics so if some1 tells me what are the basics behind this.

Thank you,

Comment: It would help if you would post details of the crash.

Comment: I see no XML tags. Ergo, this question is _not_ about multi-line XML tags.

Answer (score 4):

Well if the top link is in XML and hasn't had its ampersands escaped you'll not have well formed XML.

& should be escaped as `&amp;`

Comment: but it say 'e=UTF8' which i assume means encoding = UTF8 shouldn't that be enough ?

Comment: No, it doesn't matter what encoding you use, & must be escaped, it's a reserved character. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms145315%28v=sql.90%29.aspx

Comment: thanks a lot. i was reading up about it. i appreciate the help !!

Comment: do u mind voting up the question? i know its a little too late but just i realized these "vote" rules..